# Modify Linux kernel config file

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, android-kernel

How do I modify `.config` file in linux kernel?

When I type `make device_defconfig` a `.config` file is in created in the kernel directory. But when I type `make menuconfig` the `.config` file is modified. I would like to modify the `<device>_defconfig` in `menuconfig`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.config` file is not generally supposed to be modified manually, event though you can.

The clean and simple way is:

1. `make <device>_defconfig`
2. `make menuconfig`

   - edit
   - exit saving changes
3. `make savedefconfig`

   - creates a file named `defconfig`
4. `cp defconfig arch/$ARCH/configs/<device>_defconfig`

   - where `$ARCH` is the CPU architecture, e.g. `arm`

A defconfig is similar to `.config`, except it contains only values that differ from their default values. As such they are much shorter and readable. The entire `.config` is very verbose but it's what `make menuconfig` edits and what the kernel needs to build.

Comment: thank you! one step is you might need to do `export ARCH=arm64` before the first step.

Comment: @dazza5000 Sure, if you are cross-compiling then you need to set ARCH beforehand.